# Pentaho reports + JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, reporting, business-intelligence, pentaho

I want to develop a tiny JSF portal  containing pre-designed pentaho reports. My question is : how to embed pentaho reports and how to pass parameters from jsf to the report engine. thanks.

Comment: have you read http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/Pentaho+reports+integration+with+portlets+web+application ?

Comment: that tutorial talk about calling an XACTION based report, and thats not what i need, i hope u re qualified to answer the question :)

Comment: I just noticed that jsf is mention over there... thought it might help you... I didn't answered your question, just posted a comment... b.t.w while doing a short googling I noticed that it was recommended by others to use diff reports engine while working with JSF (not 100% sure)

Answer (score 0):

```
final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ClassicEngineBoot.getInstance().start();
try {
  // load report definition
  ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager();
  manager.registerDefaults();
  manager.registerDefaultLoaders();

  ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();

  String reportPath = "file:" + extContext.getRealPath("aaaaaaaaaaaaa.prpt");

  Resource res = manager.createDirectly(new URL(reportPath), MasterReport.class);
  MasterReport report = (MasterReport) res.getResource();
  report.getParameterValues().put("x1","%" + current.getx1() +"%");
  report.getParameterValues().put("x2","%" + current.getx2() +"%");

  HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse =
    (HttpServletResponse) extContext.getResponse();
  httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/rtf");
  httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=\"bbbbbbbbb.rtf\"");

  RTFReportUtil.createRTF(report, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
} catch (ReportProcessingException ex) {
}
```